# How to filter output of a URL

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a URL and when I send a request by curl, I get a big output.

```
curl https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/lXhkG/vt/frame -H "Accept: application/json" -s
```

I get: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/QM6FN8MZ#L

But I just want to get the URL of 720p, I mean just:

```
https:\/\/caspian1.cdn.asset.aparat.com\/aparat-video\/de54245e862b62249b6b7958c734276547445778-720p.apt?wmsAuthSign=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6IjQ2NDJhYmQ4NGFiN2UzNDJkNGMxZWI3ZTNkMzlmZmQ5IiwiZXhwIjoxNjY5ODA5NzI1LCJpc3MiOiJTYWJhIElkZWEgR1NJRyJ9.havkkhJyXjBt_jHPVv4poEVb65_7tRsLIxO5pCO7tGE
```

Any idea how to do it?

I'm trying to use grep but I don't know how to remove other things from else 720p URL.

```
curl https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/lXhkG/vt/frame -H "Accept: application/json" -s | grep -e "720p"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this following way

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/lXhkG/vt/frame | awk 'match($0, /http[^"]*720[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

gives output

```
https:\/\/caspian1.cdn.asset.aparat.com\/aparat-video\/de54245e862b62249b6b7958c734276547445778-720p.apt?wmsAuthSign=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6IjY1OTcxYTRkNGZiMjkyYjk0NjM0Mjk2ODVkOTc3YjEwIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY5ODIxNDM2LCJpc3MiOiJTYWJhIElkZWEgR1NJRyJ9.NI2_6nwOxLEOxhWghsR2bOqzrXINXqqscbduHpCWwok
```

Explanation: I use `wget` with information like progress bar &c turned-off (`--quiet`) and writing to standard output (`-O -`) which is piped into `awk`, which for each line is matching against following regular expression `http[^"]*720[^"]*` that is `http` followed by zero-or-more (`*`) not-quotes followed by `720` followed by zero-or-more non-quotes, if there is match I `print` substring of line containing that match. [`match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) string function sets RSTART and RLENGTH variables, which I use later in `substr`. Note: this might give false positivie if there are others URL containing `720`.

*(tested in GNU Wget 1.20.3 and GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: It's not "this might give false positivie", this **will** give false positives. Don't do this, the regexp is far too loose.

Answer (score 1):

You could go the html-parsing/json-parsing route, e.g.:

```bash
curl -s https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/lXhkG/vt/frame |

# Normalize html
xmlstarlet fo -o -H -R 2> /dev/null                                       |

# Extract relevant js bit
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '_:html/_:body/_:div/_:script' 2> /dev/null          |

# Extract relevant json
sed -nE '/^ *var +options *= */ { s///; s/;$//p; }'                       |

# Extract desired url, i.e. the 720p in this case
jq -r '.multiSRC[][] | select( .label == "720p" ) | .src'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat file | awk 'match($0,/"https?:\\\/\\\/[^"]*-720p\.apt\?[^"]*"/) { print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) }'
https:\/\/caspian1.asset.aparat.com\/aparat-video\/de54245e862b62249b6b7958c734276547445778-720p.apt?wmsAuthSign=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6ImViODhjZDNlYzZhYzk3OTBhZDc3MWJhMzIyNWQ3NmZlIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY5ODE4Mjc5LCJpc3MiOiJTYWJhIElkZWEgR1NJRyJ9.e6do9Ha9EkDS46NZDoHT2dYHSOezu_TbdGAGblfi2tM
```

The contents of `file` are what you provided in pastebin, obviously just replace `cat file` with your `curl` command.